# Does the range of a one-one function need necessarily to be equal to its co-domain?

Tags: relations

I came across a question which says-
"If a set A contains 7 elements and the set B contains 8 elements, then number of one to one mappings from A to B is:"

The answer is given **zero**

The explanation for the answer says that since n(A) is not equal to n(B) where n is the cardinal numbers of set A and B, hence number of none one mappings is zero

But I don't think this should be the answer as **it is not mentioned anywhere in the definition of one one function that its range must be equal to the co-domain**...

Comment: The given answer is wrong.

Comment: Ya it is wrong as the condition the answer is mentioning is the condition of onto function.if it had been the case where we have to find no of one one mapping from B to A then it would be 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer given is wrong. As @Sisanta Chhatoi pointed out, the question was likely referring to the number of onto functions from A to B which would be $0$.

The correct answer would be $ ^{8}C_{7} \times 7! $, as you are picking 7 out of 8 elements from B, and permuting the 7 elements of A into those 7 elements of B.

Little trick: If you want to find the number of one one functions from A to B, then the condition $n(A) \leq n(B)$ has to be satisfied, and the number of such one - one functions is $^nP_r$ or $ ^nC_r \times r!$, where $n$ is $n(B)$ and $r$ is $n(A)$.

Hope this helped.

Comment: Let's see. What was the value of $ ^8C_7$ .....